# How do I style an element when it has been focused with the tab key?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply style to an `<a>` tag when it has been focused using the tab key. The problem is, that the `:focus` also gets triggered when I activate the `<a>` with a mouse click.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `:focus` and `:active` for change styles at mouse click

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```css
a, a:link, a:active {
  color:green;
}
a:focus:not(:active) {
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test #1</a>
<a href="#">Test #2</a>
<a href="#">Test #3</a>
<a href="#">Test #4</a>
```

Comment: I never used it before, but I think that [:focus-visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) might be useful here

Comment: The above solution works, but as soon as the user clicks, the active doesn't apply anymore, and while the next page loads, the focus style is shown.

Comment: @Alon Eitan, browser support for focus-visible is pretty poor at the moment, so it's not an option for me.

Comment: @swiftlynx There's also a [polyfill](https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible) that implements this on browsers that do not support the feature